# Specify action in model

Tags: ember.js

I would like to do something like this:

```
{{#each App.myActionsArrayController}}
    <a class="btn btn-default" {{action actionId}}>actionName</a>
{{/each}}
```

Where the controller will have something like:

```
[
    { "actionId" : refresh, "actionName" : "Refresh Data" },
    ...
]
```

That is, the action handler is not hardcoded in the action handlebars helper, but specified programmatically. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As of [Ember.js 1.5.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html), this is indeed possible. Just make sure you don't put quotes around `actionId`.

Answer (score 1):

GJK is correct, they added the functionality in 1.5, but you need to be careful, the property must exist in the context (aka not within an iterated context)

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4659

Here's a working example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/saturubu/1/edit

Comment: For future reference: @kingpin2k fixed the issue that was mentioned (that the property must exist in the context). In Ember 1.6.0-beta.2 and forward this will be resolved via the standard Handlebars path resolution (so you can call `{{action someProperty.somethingElse}}` and it would work).

Comment: despite foobaring the git commit.  It was just one of those days, thanks for fixing it up.